# Editing an NSMutableDictionary sub-dictionary

Tags: objective-c

I have some NSMutableDictionary that is made from `Json` file.

```
NSMutableDictionary *result=//from json string
```

than , i need to edit that `result` ,which is built like :

```
{
    slots =     (
                {
            capacity = 1;
            slot = sybIWQGDWw;
            taken =             (
                "11:45-12:45",
                "12:45-17:45"
            );
        },
                {
            capacity = 1;
            slot = WNySjEZAmU;
            taken =             (
                "12:00-13:00",
                "13:00-18:00"
            );
        }
    );
}
```

To get array of all fields i have :

```
   NSMutableArray *slots=[result objectForKey:@"slots"];
```

than i get all dictionaries with :

```
 for(NSMutableDictionary *dic in slots)
            [dic setObject:@"1" forKey:@"slot"];//crash probably because i edit in for loop
```

Now i get crash when trying to change a field in the for loop.

How can i change a certain field ?

**EDIT**

This is how i make the dictionary from json (which is than mutable copy to result! )

```
-(NSDictionary*)getDictionaryForJsonWithString:(NSString*)string
{
    NSString *dataString=string;
    NSData *myData=[dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *dataDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    //NSLog(@"getDictionaryForJsonWithString: data is: %@",dataDic);
    return dataDic;

}


   NSMutableDictionary *result=[[self getDictionaryForJsonWithString:json] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Are you sure that `dic` is in fact a `NSMutableDictionary`, not `NSDictionary`?

Comment: As you see its mutable...

Comment: @Curnelious: *Declaring* it as NSMutableDictionary does not magically make it mutable …

Comment: Well, just to be sure, you declaring it as mutable dictionary does not always mean that it is mutable. Posting the code of how you initialize `results` might be helpful. Or you could just log in the console the class of your `dic` variables

Comment: Ok, so please let me know how can i check if its mutable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the dictionary from JSON, you need to set the option to create mutable instances, and it should probably be for both containers and leaves:

```
option: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers | NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
```

Comment: Thanks, i am not sure i understand how practically to do that ?

Comment: Are you using `NSJSONSerialisation` ?

Comment: When you use `JSONObjectWithData`, change the options as per my answer. You need contents to be mutable as well as the outer container.

Answer (score 0):

`NSMutableArray *slots=[[result objectForKey:@"slots"] mutableCopy]`;

Comment: @Wain, If you open `NSDicrionary Class Reference` you will find `Conforms to NSMutableCopying`.

Comment: But you aren't calling `mutableCopy` on a dictionary, you're calling in on an array. This results in a mutable array that contains the same (immutable) contents as the original array.